# Python - OperationalError in SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite

When I insert in DB, I get this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "word": syntax error
```

Code:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE films (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), ' +
            'img BLOB, imbd VARCHAR(30), country_year VARCHAR(50))')
con.commit()

for i in range(97):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO films (name, img, imbd) VALUES(' + names[i].text_content() + ', ' + str(urllib.request.urlopen(img[i].get('src')).read()) + ', ' + imbd[i].text_content() + ' )')
    con.commit()
    print(cur.lastrowid)
```

This string "word" from "name".

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary mistake which you are doing is that you are not enclosing the literals in quotations

```
con = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE films (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), ' +
            'img BLOB, imbd VARCHAR(30), country_year VARCHAR(50))')
con.commit()

for i in range(97):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO films (name, img, imbd) VALUES("' + names[i].text_content() + '", "' + str(urllib.request.urlopen(img[i].get('src')).read()) + '", "' + imbd[i].text_content() + '" )')
    con.commit()
    print(cur.lastrowid)
```

But if you do like this you are doing the ***greatest error*** on earth. The insert statement should instead be

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO films (name, img, imbd) VALUES(?,?,?)', (names[i].text_content(), str(urllib.request.urlopen(img[i].get('src')).read()), imbd[i].text_content()))
```

Else you are susceptable for SQL Syringing. Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html) for description as to why you have to use `?` instead of concatenation.

Finally See this picture and try to comprehend what would have gone wrong. 
[image]